# How to remove documents from Solr using regular expression in delete command

Tags: solr, solrj

I am using Solr (version 7.1.0) and have some documents in it. Each document contains 2 fields, one is a string field(**F1**) and other is float(**F2**). Now I want to delete some document from it, which are containing a specific type of URL in **F1**. Do I remove only those documents from Solr using some **regex** in `delete` command?
If I want to delete a document, which has value **"abc"** in **F1** field, the command should be like:

```
<delete><query>F1:abc</query></delete>
```

I want to use some regex here, i.e. `F1:<regex>` . Is it possible? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<delete><query>F1:/your regex here/</query></delete>
```